# Is it the OS or Samba that is restricting access to systemd on a shared folder?

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, systemd, node.js

I have two Rocky Linux 9 servers that we can call **svr1** and **svr2**.
**svr1** has Samba service installed and share the folder /home/rocky/shared_folder with this configuration:

```
[global]
#        workgroup = SAMBA
        server string = Samba Server %v
        netbios name = rocky-9
        security = user
        map to guest = bad user
        dns proxy = no
        inherit permissions = yes
        inherit acls = yes
[Private]
        path = /home/rocky/shared_folder
        valid users = @smb_group
        guest ok = no
        writable = yes
        browsable = yes
        create mask = 0775
        force create mode = 0775
        directory mask = 2775
        force directory mode = 2775
```

the smb_group has both *rocky* and *manager-client* users. The second one is the user used on **svr2** to connect and write files on the remote share.

Now, on **svr1** I need to read files written by the **svr2** from a nodejs server. This server runs as *rocky* user and is managed by *systemd*. Every time I try to read the file I get permission denied like this

```
 Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/rocky/shared_folder/651e8a58a60e0392608a1c88/context.json'
     at Object.openSync (node:fs:581:18)
     at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:457:35)
    at Object.uploadFile (/home/rocky/coinnect-grpc-ai/providers/assistant.js:83:15)
     at Object.uploadFile (/home/rocky/coinnect-grpc-ai/controllers/manager.js:171:40)
     at Object.uploadFile (/home/rocky/coinnect-grpc-ai/server/server.js:243:46)
     at handleUnary (/home/rocky/coinnect-grpc-ai/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server.js:852:17)
     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
   errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
   syscall: 'open',
   path: '/home/rocky/shared_folder/651e8a58a60e0392608a1c88/context.json'
 }
```

But if I create a test.js script that does the same thing and I run it from console it works. So I have the proof that only systemd process is getting denied, even if the running user is the same (*rocky*).

Shared folder permissions are:

```
*drwxrws---. 6 root  smb_group  169 Jan 25 12:49 shared_folder*
```

while specific file has these one:

```
*-rwxrw----. 1 manager-client smb_group 27007 Jan 25 12:38 context.json*
```

Do you know some reason why this could happen? I don't understand if depends by Samba or OS (selinux or stuff like that).

thanks

Comment: Please be aware that on commonly used distributions, AppArmor or SELinux might also be involved in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the Rocky user to the smb_group on svr1 to grant access:

```
sudo usermod -aG smb_group rocky
```

Then restart samba

You might need to adjust the file permissions on the shared_folder to allow the Rocky user to read files created by svr2:

```
sudo chmod -R 0775 /home/rocky/shared_folder
sudo chown -R rocky:smb_group /home/rocky/shared_folder
```

Ensure that the PM2 process manager also runs under the Rocky user to maintain consistent access permissions

Comment: I think the problem came from the rocky not being added correctly to smb_group. I indeed did it but with "sudo usermod -G smb_group rocky" without the a